# Google test fails to build with Intel 19 and Visual Studio c++ 19

Tags: c++, windows, unit-testing

I'm trying to embed Google Test in my project. I am using:

- Project Type:  Visual Studio 16 2019
- Toolset: Intel C++ Compiler 19.0
- Architecture:  64 bits
- CMake version: 3.16.1

I am following the instructions of [Google Test readme](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/README.md#incorporating-into-an-existing-cmake-project)

I am using the master branch (version 1.10) of Gtest repository.

Cmake runs ok, and Visual Studio solution is generated. But when building it, cmock and gtest projects fail to build with the following errors:

```
1>gtest-all.cc
1>Error #2586: \'operator=\' : decorated name length exceeded, name was truncated

1>gmock-all.cc
1>C:\Users\saa4\Downloads\googletest-master\googlemock\include\gmock/gmock-actions.h(816): message #411: class template "testing::internal::InvokeMethodAction<Class, MethodPtr>" defines no constructor to initialize the following:
1>            const member "testing::internal::InvokeMethodAction<Class, MethodPtr>::obj_ptr"
1>            const member "testing::internal::InvokeMethodAction<Class, MethodPtr>::method_ptr"
1>  struct InvokeMethodAction {
1>         ^
1>
1>C:\Users\saa4\Downloads\googletest-master\googlemock\include\gmock/gmock-actions.h(845): message #411: class template "testing::internal::InvokeMethodWithoutArgsAction<Class, MethodPtr>" defines no constructor to initialize the following:
1>            const member "testing::internal::InvokeMethodWithoutArgsAction<Class, MethodPtr>::obj_ptr"
1>            const member "testing::internal::InvokeMethodWithoutArgsAction<Class, MethodPtr>::method_ptr"
1>  struct InvokeMethodWithoutArgsAction {
1>         ^
```

When setting the compiler to Visual C++ it builds normally. Do I need te set any extra configuration parameter for Intel?

Comment: For the #2586 'error', [this link](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/diagnostic-2586-decorated-name-length-exceeded) may be helpful. The two #411 'diagnostic messages' can probably be safely ignored.

Comment: There are switches to disable specific diagnostics in the Intel C++ compiler - but I don't currently have access to my PC with Intel on it, so I can't be more helpful on that front.

Comment: @AdrianMole Thank you for your comments. I have already visited the link. However it seem a pretty old one and talks about a warning that can be "safely ignored". It seems it was the case for older Intel compiler version, but for Intel 19 this is not a warning any more, and breaks the build. Since it is compiling for Visual C++ compilers I was wondering if it was a matter of build set-up.